# Eclipse not automatically refreshing resources in src/main/resources

Tags: eclipse

In my `Eclipse` preferences, I have "Refresh using native hooks or polling" selected.

If I make a change to a Java file outside of Eclipse, the project that contains that Java file automatically refreshes and rebuilds that file as it should.  However, if I make a change to a file under `src/main/resources/...` from an external editor, it is not automatically refreshed.  I have to select the project and press **F5** to get it to refresh.

Is there a way to configure Eclipse to automatically refresh any resources under `src/main/resources`?

Answer (score 0):

In `Eclipse`

1. Run > External Tools > External Tools Configuration
2. Create a new Program configuration Point the location to an exe that is very fast
3. On the Refresh tab, choose Refresh Resources upon completion, The Entire Workspace
4. On the Build tab, deselect Build before launch

Comment: You still have to manually call an External Tool before launching your program.  Is there a way to configure the project to call this external tool automatically when launching your program?